# PHP Pagination(Next Pages show data sortBY ID, not Name,Code, or what else I want)

Tags: php, pagination

I got problem that, my Pagination first pages sortby Id,name,code or whatever I want. But next pages automatic short by id, not option I want. Don't understand how to make this work. Tried diffirent things, but same result.

This is how my code looks:

```
   public function selectParts()
    {
        try
        {

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM partcatalogue");                                                                                                                             
            $stmt->execute();
            $total = $stmt->fetchColumn();                                                                                                                          

            $perpage = 10;
            $pages = ceil($total / $perpage);

            $get_pages = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

            $data = array(

                'options' => array(
                    'default'   => 1,
                    'min_range' => 1,
                    'max_range' => $pages
                    )
            );

            $number = trim($get_pages);
            $number = filter_var($number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $data);
            $range = $perpage * ($number - 1);

            $prev = $number - 1;
            $next = $number + 1;

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT part_id,image,name,manufacture,category,code FROM partcatalogue ORDER BY part_id LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
            $stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();


            if((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "sortbyId")
            {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT part_id,image,name,manufacture,category,code FROM partcatalogue ORDER BY part_id ASC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
                $stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            }

            if((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "sortbyName")
            {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT part_id,image,name,manufacture,category,code FROM partcatalogue ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
                $stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            }

            if((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "sortbyCode")
            {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT part_id,image,name,manufacture,category,code FROM partcatalogue ORDER BY code ASC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
                $stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            }

            if((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "sortbyManufacture")
            {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT part_id,image,name,manufacture,category,code FROM partcatalogue ORDER BY manufacture ASC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
                $stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();

                $result = $stmt->fetchAll();$stmt->execute();
            }

            if((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "sortbyCategory")
            {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT part_id,image,name,manufacture,category,code FROM partcatalogue ORDER BY category ASC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
                $stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();

                $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            }

            echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>"; ?><a href="ViewParts.php?action=sortbyId" class="btn btn-default">Id</a></th><?php
            echo "<th>"; ?><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Image</a></th><?php
            echo "<th>"; ?><a href="ViewParts.php?action=sortbyName" class="btn btn-default">Name</a></th><?php
            echo "<th>"; ?><a href="ViewParts.php?action=sortbyCode" class="btn btn-default">Code</a></th><?php
            echo "<th>"; ?><a href="ViewParts.php?action=sortbyManufacture" class="btn btn-default">Manufacture</a></th><?php
            echo "<th>"; ?><a href="ViewParts.php?action=sortbyCategory" class="btn btn-default">Category</a></th><?php
            echo "<th>"; ?><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a><?php
            echo "<th>"; ?><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Delete</a><?php
            echo "</tr>";

            foreach($result as $part){ 

            echo "<td>"; echo $part['part_id']; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>"; echo "<img src='../../Images/Part/".$part['image']."' width='50' height='50'/>"; echo"</td>";  
            echo "<td>"; echo $part['name']; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>"; echo $part['code']; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>"; echo $part['manufacture']; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>"; echo $part['category']; echo "</td>";          
            echo "<td>"; ?><a href="ViewParts.php?action=edit&part_id=<?php echo $part['part_id']?>" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a><?php echo"</td>";     
            echo "<td>"; ?><a href="ViewParts.php?action=delete&part_id=<?php echo $part['part_id']?>" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to DELETE?');">Delete</a><?php echo"</td>";
            echo "</hr>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</hr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";

                if($result && count($result) > 0)
                {
                    echo "<h4>Total pages ($pages)</h4>";

                    # first page
                    if($number <= 1)
                        echo "<span>&laquo; prev</span> | <a href=\"?page=$next\">next &raquo;</a>";

                    # last page
                    elseif($number >= $pages)
                        echo "<a href=\"?page=$prev\">&laquo; prev</a> | <span>next &raquo;</span>";

                    # in range
                    else
                        echo "<a href=\"?page=$prev\">&laquo; prev</a> | <a href=\"?page=$next\">next &raquo;</a>";
                }

                else
                {
                    echo "<p>No results found.</p>";
                }


            return $result; 
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }
```

Comment: Well you are going to have to save the desired sort order from the first request so you can reuse the correct order on the second and subsequent pagination requests. Maybe the Session would be a good place to save this

Comment: @RiggsFolly Im willing to do that, but can't really understand how to make it happen. Made session with variable, but don't really understand how to display other values if session = Name(for example)